# Pure Blood devil and their Chess pieces

Tags: high-school-dxd

After war, the number of pure blood devil number decreased and almost went extinct except for 3 clan who did survive. So they are taking humans to increase their numbers in the form of chess pieces. I have only watched the anime and information about **Raiser Phoenix**'s chess pieces was very little. However, it was mentioned that his own sister **Ravel Phoenix** was a bishop who was revived as **demon**. **What does it mean - isn't she a demon already?**

Does that mean **Rias Gremory** is also servant of higher rank devil, or every pure blood devil are king and they choose their chess pieces/servant except **Ravel Phoenix**'s case where she died and revived as demon as other piece of chess?

And to be chosen as a chess piece, must the person die or not, since the word **revived** is used. What are the conditions for someone to be chosen the servant? Can it be anyone?

Answer (score 5):

I read the light novel, and you got it wrong. It wasn't that only 3 devils survived. Think of it more like they were an endangered species (more than 3), and to increase their number one devil created the chess pieces. When a devil wants a servant, it doesn't limit to just humans, it can be any creature (devils included, i.e. Ravel). For example, a dragon that trains Issei is actually a devil as well. As for someone having to die before they can be a devil is false, it's more like they are just reborn as a devil when they are turn into a servant.

Both Rias and Ruval are pure bloods meaning their parents are devils. In Rias' case, she has no King, but she could if another devil wanted her as their servant (which is the case with Ravel).

Lastly, not all Kings are pure bloods. I'm pretty sure the first season explains that if Issei tries hard enough, he can get his own set of chess pieces making him the King.

Comment: Please check whether I got the names and terminologies correct.

Comment: @user7746 3 in my question mean 3 clan, like **Gremory**,**Phoenix** with pure blood. Did you mean same ? And i think you did not answer my last two question about condition.

Comment: @mirroroftruth: The name of the daughter of Phenex house in katanaka is レイヴェル・フェニックス (Reiveru Fenikusu), so Ravel is one way to write it (and I think it fits better this way). There is also Ruval (ルヴァル Ruvaru), who is the eldest son of the Phenex house. However, I don't know who the answerer is referring to.

Comment: @nhahtdh i misunderstand it. when you wrote Ruval because i was asking about Ravel. I think i should edit may question with appropriate name

Answer (score 1):

From what i remember from the light novel:

In DxD a set of chess pieces are granted to "high class" demons, demons are a tiered class society, so if Issei managed to climb the social ladder he will be granted his set of chess pieces despite he being a human born demon. Demons are extremely elitists so climbing is really hard, that's the reason that most sets of pieces are in possession of pure blood demons.

Also after the war there were 72 surviving houses "the 72 pilars" not just 3, but their numbers were scarce, so in order to increase their numbers they came up with the chess piece system (minor spoiler: heaven will do something similar), those 72 clans are what is considered pure blood, because of desesperate measures taken to increase numbers after the war